# How do I simulate menu button on Android 8?

Tags: 8.0-oreo, samsung-galaxy-s7

So far I've used the Assistant Menu on my Galaxy S7 as recommended in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141278/how-do-i-simulate-menu-button-on-android-6), but after a recent update the assistant menu no longer contains the old menu button.

The "long press" suggestions in the answers doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here.  Found an app called "Menu Button" in the play store which has solved my issue with an old app (Loot personal finance).  I have no association with this app.